# I want to modify href link append characters using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://mytestsite.com/search/label/Technology?m=1" rel="tag"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://mytestsite.com/search/label/Science?m=1" rel="tag"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://mytestsite.com/search/label/Invention?m=1" rel="tag"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://mytestsite.com/search/label/History?m=1" rel="tag"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://mytestsite.com/search/label/Humanity?m=1" rel="tag"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

I want to remove ?m=1 and add &max-results=7&m=1. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: [Google it](https://www.google.lv/search?q=change+href+parameter+jquery&oq=edit+href+para&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.5940j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$('nav-wrapper a').attr('href', function(_, value){
    return value.replace('m=1', 'max-results=7&m=1');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Saptal. Your script is also working.

Answer (score 1):

try `replace()`

```
href = $('a').attr('href')

$('a').attr('href', href.replace('m=1', 'max-results=7&m=1') )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It worked for me as I expected.

Comment: All anchor element's `href` will have same url see https://jsfiddle.net/bnkgbywz/

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct. But simple string concate will also work for you.

```
href = $('a').attr('href');
$('a').attr('href', href+'&max-results=7');
```